# Show a conditional message on Shipping Method Step Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add a disclaimer message on the Shipping Method stage in the Magento onepage checkout to those users whose shipping address is located in Canada. My store is US based, but does ship to Canada, but I want users from Canada to know they are responsible for any duties and taxes. Is there a way to add that message if their shipping address is Canadian?

Answer (score 6):

The quick way (not the prettiest though) will be to modify your `app/design/frontend/YOUR_INTERFACE/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml` file and add the following code at the very top:

```
<?php if($this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountry() == 'CA' ||
         ($this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getSameAsBilling() && $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getCountry() == 'CA')): ?>

    BLAME CANADA !!!
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Will this work with guest checkout as well or only if they log in?

Comment: Yes it will as `quote` object has nothing to do with customer.

Comment: Do you know why when I choose 'Ship to this address' under the Billing Address form, that it wouldn't show the disclaimer on the Shipping Method step? If I choose to 'Ship to different address' and then apply Canada to that form, it then brings up the disclaimer text on the Shipping Method step.

Comment: Got your edit. Still not working for me when a customer skips the Shipping Address by clicking the 'Ship to this address' under the Billing Address form. Any thoughts?

Comment: try to echo `$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getSameAsBilling()` before `if` clause.

Comment: Thanks Tim, your solution saved alot of my time and efforts :)